# How to keep custom object sequence property in model when there are multiple lists of that type used in application

Tags: c#, wpf, static

I have a wpf application with MVVM pattern. There is a view which displays the warnings (text) on screen, which are of type WarningModel.cs

In my ViewModel I have 3 properties of type `ObservableCollection<WarningModel>()`, these are bound to 3 different grids (telerik for wpf grids). Three grids because there are 3 types of warnings.
My requirement is when user adds new warning (new object of type WarningModel) into the grid, that object should be assigned an order sequence starting with 1 followed by 2 and so on for next object.

What I tried is added a static field in Warning.cs which will be auto incremented each time the constructor is called. Now the problem is since there are 3 ObservableCollection each time the object is instantiated from any of the collection, sequence gets incremented but all the three collection should maintain their own sequence.

What else can be employed here to achieve the desired output.

Here are my classes

```
 public class Warning
    {
        public string MESSAGE { get; set; }

        private int _type;
        public int TYPE 
        {
            get { return _type; }

            set
            {
                if (value != _type)
                    _type = value;
            }
        }
        public int SORT_ORDER { get; set; }
        public static int SORT_SEQUENCE = 0;
        public Warning()
        {
            SORT_ORDER = Interlocked.Increment(ref SORT_SEQUENCE);
        }
    }



   public class WarningsViewModel
        {
            public ObservableCollection<WarningModel> WarningBP { get; set; }
            public ObservableCollection<WarningModel> WarningPP { get; set; }
            public ObservableCollection<WarningModel> WarningPB { get; set; }

            public VoyageInfoViewModel()
            {
                WarningBP = new ObservableCollection<WarningModel>();
                WarningPP = new ObservableCollection<WarningModel>();
                Warning PB = new ObservableCollection<WarningModel>();
            }
        }
```

Comment: The WarningModel objects should not manage their own sequence number. Imagine a potential use case where one instance is an element of more than one collection. Or a case where you want to reorder the elements in a collection.

Comment: You may get the number by something like `WarningBP.IndexOf(warningObject)`.

Comment: I'd expect to see `DateTime` instead of `int`, not only you may want to show time of warning, but it's also great to order by.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach handler for `CollectionChanged` of `ObservableCollection` and assign ID as index of inserted item.

```cs
public VoyageInfoViewModel()
{
    WarningBP = new ObservableCollection<WarningModel>();
    WarningBP.CollectionChanged += WarningCollectionChanged;
    ...
}
private void WarningCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
      for (var i = 0; i < e.NewItems.Count; i++)
         ((Warning)e.NewItems[i]).SORT_ORDER = e.NewStartingIndex + i + 1;
}
```

If you allow user also to delete warnings and want SORT_ORDER be recalculated on deletion you can write handler as:

```cs
private void WarningCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   for (var i = 0; i < ((ICollection)sender).Count; i++)        
      ((Warning)((IList)sender)[i]).SORT_ORDER = i + 1;
}
```

Comment: Maybe it make sense to create own collection (wrapper over `ObservableCollection<T>`) to make sure everything is synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

You could for example create a custom `ObservableCollection<T>` that sets the sequence number of added items. Something like this:

```
public class SequencedObservableCollection : ObservableCollection<WarningModel>
{
    private int _sequenceCounter = 0;

    protected override void InsertItem(int index, WarningModel item)
    {
        item.SORT_ORDER = ++_sequenceCounter;

        base.InsertItem(index, item);
    }
}

public abstract class WarningModel
{
    public int SORT_ORDER { get; set; }
}
```

Don't forget to change the type of your source properties in the view model:

```
public SequencedObservableCollection  WarningBP { get; set; }
public SequencedObservableCollection  WarningPP { get; set; }
public SequencedObservableCollection  WarningPB { get; set; }
```